# How can I plot the log file?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

Does anyone know any function for plotting the obtained measures in Caffe? I would like to plot train loss, test loss, and accuracy, train moving average and etc. in one plot. Is there any function except Caffe built-in function that is available online?

Edited:
First, I ran `parse_log.py` file (the following command):

```
$python /path/to/caffe/tools/extra/parse_log.py /logfile_path/logfile.log /output_dir
```

Two files are created based on the log file (`lofile.log.train` and `logfile.log.test`). After that,I ran `plot_training_log.py` file. It has options like:

```
    0: Test accuracy  vs. Iters
    1: Test accuracy  vs. Seconds
    2: Test loss  vs. Iters
    3: Test loss  vs. Seconds
    4: Train learning rate  vs. Iters
    5: Train learning rate  vs. Seconds
    6: Train loss  vs. Iters
    7: Train loss  vs. Seconds
```

Whenever, I chose option **3**, it is showing the following graph:
[image]
and by choosing option **0** :
[image]
However, whenever, I want to plot train-loss figure, it is giving error:

```
$python /path/to/caffe/tools/extra/plot_training_log.py.example 6 /output_dir/train_loss_cnn1.png ./logfile.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ss/caffe-master/tools/extra/plot_training_log.py.example", line 191, in <module>
    plot_chart(chart_type, path_to_png, path_to_logs)
  File "/home/ss/caffe-master/tools/extra/plot_training_log.py.example", line 117, in plot_chart
    data = load_data(data_file, x, y)
  File "/home/ss/caffe-master/tools/extra/plot_training_log.py.example", line 88, in load_data
    data[1].append(float(fields[field_idx1].strip()))
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0.522037s/50
```

My question can be folded into three parts:

1. Are the plots correct? Is the network behaving well?
2. From which point this error stem from? I have the following columns in `logfile.log.train` (#Iters|Seconds |TrainingLoss |LearningRate).
3. How can I show all chart types in one plot? I tried to include them by comma, like 0,2,3,6, however, it is showing error.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`parse_log.py`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/tools/extra/parse_log.py) found in [`$CAFFE_ROOT/tools/extra`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/tools/extra/).
This python utility helps parsing and distilling information from caffe running log.

Comment: Thank Shai, I tried this one before, It is taking just one number for showing different plots separately. For example, by writing number 6 is plotting only train loss. Thanks again

Comment: @S.EB this tool is generic, you can adapt it to fit your exact needs.

Answer (score 0):

start training your model by executing the command below:

```
/home/ubuntu/caffe/build/tools/caffe train --solver /home/ubuntu/yourpath/solver.prototxt 2>&1 | tee /home/ubuntu/yourpath/model_train.log
```

The training logs will be stored under yourpath/model_train.log.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at `caffe`'s built in plot scripts, but I use the script from [here](https://github.com/yassersouri/omgh/blob/master/src/scripts/vis_finetune.py). This only plots your train/test loss, but you can add moving average calculation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link

Answer (score 0):

Consider also installing [DIGITS](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS), that provides a real-time plot showing all that kind of stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, What exactly DIGITS is? Is it like a graphical user interface for Caffe? How can I install it on a device that I have installed Caffe on that? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is more or less a GUI for caffe. It is very handy in datasets and models management and organization, plus has this real-time plot feature that literally saves you during training. Another interesting feature is the possibility to visualize the output of each layer with a given image as input. 
If you go to the GitHub repo I posted above you'll see the installation guide. Unfortunately it's not available for all the platform Caffe is available for.